# Best way to merge and transform keys and arrays from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{ role1: ["id1", "id2", "id3"], role2: ["id1", "id2"], role3: ["id2", "id4"] }
```

I would like to transform this into an array of objects, making the ids the unique identifiers and the roles into arrays, like so:

```
[
  { id: "id1", roles: ["role1", "role2"] },
  { id: "id2", roles: ["role1", "role2", "role3"] },
  { id: "id3", roles: ["role1"] },
  { id: "id4", roles: ["role3"] },
]
```

This is how I do it right now, but I'm not sure if there's a better way. It feels like I'm overcomplicating things.

```js
const obj = {
  role1: ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
  role2: ["id1", "id2"],
  role3: ["id2", "id4"]
};
const users = [];

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, ids]) => {
  ids.forEach(id => {
    const user = users.find(x => x.id === id);
    if (user) {
      user.roles.push(key);
      return;
    }
    users.push({
      id,
      roles: [key]
    });
  });
});

console.log(users);
```

Comment: An Array makes no sense. `id: "id1",` makes also no sense since IDs are unique and the property `id` becomes redundant. And btw Arrays are used to preserve a specific order, whilst in your case it's generated and irrelevant. Given that, the property `roles` becomes redundant as well. Instead I would create a *usersRoles* Object: `{"id1": ["role1", "role2"], "id2": ["role1", "role2", "role3"]}`

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan, that's good input! But in my case I will have more properties being connected to each user later on in the code, so I guess that would make Array a valid option? And I also need to be able to sort it by multiple properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably just transform it into an object like so:

```js
const obj = {
  role1: ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
  role2: ["id1", "id2"],
  role3: ["id2", "id4"]
};
let userDict = {};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, ids]) => {
  ids.forEach(id => {
    userDict[id] = (userDict[id] || []);
    userDict[id].push(key);
  });
});

let users = Object.entries(userDict).map(([id, roles]) => ({ id, roles }));

console.log(users);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Or even use `reduce` like so:

```js
const obj = {
  role1: ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
  role2: ["id1", "id2"],
  role3: ["id2", "id4"]
};
let userDict = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [role, ids]) => {
  ids.forEach(id => {
    acc[id] = (acc[id] || []);
    acc[id].push(role);
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

let users = Object.entries(userDict).map(([id, roles]) => ({ id, roles }));

console.log(users);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Either option is more concise and simple than using an array all the way through.

Answer (score 1):

The First thing I get all id from that object by using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) (*to avoid duplicates*) with [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
const obj = {
  role1: ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
  role2: ["id1", "id2"],
  role3: ["id2", "id4"],
};
const objsId = [
  ...new Set(
    Object.values(obj) //[["id1","id2","id3"],["id1","id2"],["id2","id4"]]
      .flat() //['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id1', 'id2', 'id2', 'id4']
  ),
]; 
console.log(objsId); //['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4']
```

The second thing is creating an object from that array by using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

> Method transforms a list of key-value pairs into an object.

```js
const objsId = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'];
const idRoles = Object.fromEntries(
  objsId.map((id) => [id, []]) //[["id1",[]],["id2",[]],["id3",[]],["id4",[]]]
); 
console.log(idRoles) //{"id1":[],"id2":[],"id3":[],"id4":[]}
```

Finally loop over our *array* `objsId` and for each id, loop over your *object* `obj` entries using [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
 with *for..of*
And if the current id exists in roles, So add affect that role into `idRoles`

```js
const obj = {
  role1: ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
  role2: ["id1", "id2"],
  role3: ["id2", "id4"],
};
const objsId = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'];
const idRoles = { id1: [], id2: [], id3: [], id4: [] };
for (const id of objsId) {
  for (const [role, ids] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (ids.includes(id)) idRoles[id].push(role);
  }
}
console.log(idRoles);
```

```js
const obj = {
  role1: ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
  role2: ["id1", "id2"],
  role3: ["id2", "id4"],
};
const objsId = [
  ...new Set(
    Object.values(obj) //[["id1","id2","id3"],["id1","id2"],["id2","id4"]]
      .flat() //['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id1', 'id2', 'id2', 'id4']
  ),
]; //['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4']

const idRoles = Object.fromEntries(
  objsId.map((id) => [id, []]) //[["id1",[]],["id2",[]],["id3",[]],["id4",[]]]
); //{"id1":[],"id2":[],"id3":[],"id4":[]}

for (const id of objsId) {
  for (const [role, ids] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (ids.includes(id)) idRoles[id].push(role);
  }
}
const result = [];
for (let [id, roles] of Object.entries(idRoles)) {
  result.push({ id, roles });
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Answer (score -1):

just another version with Lodash library

```
const obj = {
  role1: ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
  role2: ["id1", "id2"],
  role3: ["id2", "id4"]
};

const users = _.chain(obj)
  .entries()
  .reduce((accm, [role, ids]) => {
    ids.forEach((id) => (accm[id] || (accm[id] = [])).push(role));
    return accm;
  }, {})
  .entries()
  .map(([id, roles]) => ({ id, roles }));
```